# Completeness preserved under homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,d')$ metric spaces and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a homeomorphism.

if $(X,d)$ is complete, is the property of be complete preserved under $f?$ i,e. Under this conditions $Y$ must be complete too.

I think that this is not true but I can't find a counterexample.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: What about $\mathbb{R}$ and $]0,1[$ ?

Comment: Completeness is not a property of topological spaces, but rather that of metric spaces. So it needs not be preserved by homeomorphisms, which only concern topological structure.

Comment: @SangchulLee yes, I agree. This is the reason of my question. I wanted a explicit example to confirm my thoughts.

Comment: At least being *completely metrisable* is a topological property.

Answer (score 2):

Simple example:

$\Bbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$ are homeomorphic via $$x \mapsto \frac{1}{1+2^{-x}}$$ Here $\Bbb{R}$ is complete whereas $(0,1)$ is not!

Comment: I thought in this spaces, but I wasn't can find a homeomorphism between them. Thank you